# Inserting variable into string

Tags: powershell, variables, copy-item

Newer to PoSh and having some troubles inserting a variable into a string. I am packaging an application using the PowerShell Application Deployment Toolkit, and here is a snippet of my script (Get-LoggedOnUser and Copy-File work within the application):

### Get logged on user

```
           $user=Get-LoggedOnUser
```

### Copy plist file

```
 Copy-File -Path "$dirSupportFiles\com.iliumsoft.ewallet.plist"
-destination "C:\Users\$user\AppData\Roaming\com.iliumsoft.ewallet.plist"
```

I looked through some postings here and elsewhere on the web and most questions/solutions appended the variable to the end of the path. I played around with Join-Path but could not get that to work either.

Answer (score 1):

So I'm assuming you are using the Get-LoggedOnUser script from here:

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-LoggedOnUser-Gathers-7cbe93ea

For this to work, it would be easiest to put it into a function:

```
function Get-LoggedOnUSer {
   << Script Code >>
}
```

Then put call it to the variable :

```
$item = Get-LoggedOnUSer
```

As for the copy file, you are passing an array of items into the $user variable so you would need to change that to:

```
$item = Get-LoggedOnUSer
$user = $item.UserName

Copy-Item -Path "$dirSupportFiles\com.iliumsoft.ewallet.plist" -destination "C:\Users\$user\AppData\Roaming\"
```